# Issue for converting a datetime format using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset that contains a `date_time` column in this format:

```
date_time
01.01.2018 00:00 - 01.01.2018 00:15 (UTC)
01.01.2018 00:15 - 01.01.2018 00:30 (UTC)
01.01.2018 00:30 - 01.01.2018 00:45 (UTC)
01.01.2018 00:45 - 01.01.2018 01:00 (UTC)
.
.
.
```

By reading this dataset using pandas, I need to convert `date_time` column from the type `object` to `datetime` by using the following:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])
```

However, I get this error

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 643, in parse
    raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 01.01.2018 00:00 - 01.01.2018 00:15 (UTC)
```

Clearly, pandas is not aware of `date_time` original format. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, what you have is a range, not a single datetime.

Start with splitting it into start and end datetimes:

```
df[['dt_start', 'dt_end']] = df['date_time'].str.split(' - ', expand = True)
```

Now, starting datetime converts without issues (use `utc = True` if you want to keep it timezone-aware):

```
df['dt_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_start'], utc = True)
```

Ending datetime needs a little help in feeding it the format manually since `to_datetime` parser with arguments at default can't recognize `(UTC)` stamp:

```
df['dt_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_end'], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M (UTC)', utc = True)
```